# Why is my image file name red in colour after I tried to replace the file with another file?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, dart

Tried to switch an image file in my image folder for flutter, I did not safe delete and after I swap it, the file is perpetually red. There are other files which are dark brown in colour too.

Tried doing package get but to no avail

[image]

Comment: That's a git status I think, did you try adding that file to version control (e.g. `git add images/logo.png`)?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem before, just right click on the file then select `Git -> Add` and it will turn back to blue.